# How to check if number consist of number with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say if i have a multiple numbers and one is 54833928. I type into input '5483' and if i click some element i would want to show all these numbers to there. String.prototype.contains -> helped me with words, but how can i accomplish same thing with numbers. So i have like..

```
<div class="item" data-number="5553498">
some random text
</div>

<div class="item" data-number="5552134">
some random text
</div>

<div class="item" data-number="554325">
some random text
</div>

<div class="item" data-number="5555432">
some random text
</div>

<input type="text" placeholder="number"><span class="click_find">find</span>

js -

var something_obj = {
            "number": "empty"
};

if (( number.contains(something_obj.number) || something_obj.number == 'empty') { blabla }
```

cant get numbers with using .contains, only something_obj.number == number, but ofcourse it only gives me exact numbers, so i have to put only right number right away and if i put less numbers it returns 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var num = 54833928;

num.toString().includes("5483"); //true
```

**[String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)**

Comment: Worked! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Convert that number to String temporarily : 
And to convert it , just use `+` operator with empty string

```
5553498+'' === '5553498'
```

Now you can handle it as String and use `String#prototype#contains`

Answer (score 0):

You can typecast Number to String using:

```
var str = String(num);
```

and apply `String.prototype.contains`.